# How to make margins work separately on inline elements with CSS?

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on a navigation bar for my website and I'm trying to space everything centred evenly in the bar, but for some reason, I can't get things to work out evenly. Either margins don't work, or they do but not all the way, and it's getting quite frustrating. Here's my code:

```js
body {
  margin: 0 px;
  font - family: Helvetica;
}
.navbar {
  background - color: grey;
  width: 100 % ;
  height: 70 px;
  text - align: center;
}
.items li {
  display: inline - block;
  padding - left: 50 px;
}
.items a {
  text - decoration: none;
  color: #333;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 20px;
     padding-top: -25px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="items">
      <img src="logo1.png" style="height:55px;padding-top:7.5px;">
      <li><a href="apparel.html">Apparel</a></li>
      <li><a href="ea.html">Equipment & Accessories</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: "`padding-top: -25px;`" padding doesn't take negative value(s).

Comment: li items must have a ul or a ol as a parent

Comment: In your snippet you set the css code in js section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center vertically links with the logo, use `vertical-align:middle;`.

Also, If you set margin or padding don't set it to `<a>` because it's an item with `inline` properties but set it on `li` items which are inline-block.

In addition to that, it's strange to write `li` items without `ul` container.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
.navbar {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100% ;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

.items img
{
vertical-align:middle;
}

.items li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.items a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="items">
      <img src="logo1.png" style="height:55px;padding-top:7.5px;">
      <li><a href="apparel.html">Apparel</a></li>
      <li><a href="ea.html">Equipment & Accessories</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:See it in full page!**

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
.navbar {
 background-color: grey;
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}

.items {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.items li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 50px;
}
.items a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #333;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
 <div class="items">
  <img src="logo1.png" style="height:55px;padding-top:7.5px;">
  <li><a href="apparel.html">Apparel</a></li>
  <li><a href="ea.html">Equipment & Accessories</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
 </div>
</div>
```